# How to detect outliers in an array of doubles?

Tags: c#, math

I'm trying to determine whether or not there is data outliers in a list of doubles.  Basically if anything is below 10 percent of the limits or above 90 percent.  I have the following code working, but it doesn't work properly with negative numbers and I'm not seeing what is wrong.  Is there a better way to approach there, or is there something glaring in the code or math?

```
public bool DataHasOutliers(IEnumerable<double> results, Limits limits)
{
    foreach (double result in results)
    {
        //detect if any result values are in the low or high regions of the acceptable limits
        double deltaAbsolute = (limits.High - limits.Low) < 0 ? (limits.High - limits.Low) * -1 : limits.High - limits.Low;
        double absoluteResult = result < 0 ? result * -1 : result;
        double lowLimitAbsolute = limits.Low < 0 ? limits.Low * -1 : limits.Low;
        double upperThreshold = 0.9 * deltaAbsolute + limits.Low;
        double lowerThreshold = 0.1 * deltaAbsolute + limits.Low;
        if (absoluteResult >= upperThreshold)
        {
            "".Dump("Upper threshold violated");
            return true;
        }
        if (absoluteResult <= lowerThreshold)
        {
            "".Dump("Lower threshold violated");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public class Limits
{
    public double High { get; set; }
    public double Low { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think code is good and simple enough, one doesnt need to make things more complex

Comment: Yes, the code doesn't handle negative numbers correctly. You can use the `Math.Abs()` method to get rid of the sign on the `limits.High` and `limits.Low` numbers before you do your calculations.

Comment: What is the expected behavior when you have negative numbers? Can the limits also be negative? I don't think simply taking the absolute value of numbers (and limits) is a good solution.

Comment: Using lowLimitAbsolute is not sensible.  You need to use Limits.Low so the thresholds can be negative.

Comment: The limits can also be negative, yes.

Answer (score 2):

If the limits are `[-10, 0]` and a result is `-5`, with the current code you'll effectively be checking if `5` is in `[11, 19]`, which is not correct.

I suggest to keep the sign of the boundaries increasing/decreasing them by the 1/10-th of the range and then check the original result value against this reduced range:

```
double deltaAbsolute = Math.Abs(limits.High - limits.Low);
double lowerThreshold = limits.Low + 0.1 * deltaAbsolute;
double upperThreshold = limits.High - 0.1 * deltaAbsolute;
if (result >= upperThreshold)
{
    "".Dump("Upper threshold violated");
    return true;
}
if (result <= lowerThreshold)
{
    "".Dump("Lower threshold violated");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you recalculating limits IN the loop.
If High > Low then you don't need any of the absolute stuff.

```
public bool DataHasOutliers(IEnumerable<double> results, Limits limits)
{
    if(limits.High < limits.Low) 
    {
         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
    double delta = limits.High - limits.Low;
    double upperThreshold = 0.9 * delta + limits.Low;
    double lowerThreshold = 0.1 * delta + limits.Low;
    foreach (double result in results)
    {
        //detect if any result values are in the low or high regions of the acceptable limits
        if (result >= upperThreshold)
        {
            "".Dump("Upper threshold violated");
            return true;
        }
        if (result <= lowerThreshold)
        {
            "".Dump("Lower threshold violated");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```